# How to get grand parent Object ID for a child in Agile Central API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rally

I am working on my application with Rally API , I am forming tree structure using Rally Data. I am pulling from 'ProjectsPermissions' table with relation. Here I am facing a issue like below:

A - GP - Have Access 
 B- Parent - Not Have Access 
  C- Children - Have Access.

I need to form a tree node C under A node, but data is like Immediate parent relation to child, and if parent dosen't have access I am getting parent attribute as null. By this I am not able to form tree. can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have run into one of the weird corner cases around permissions and projects in the Web Services API.  There is currently no supported way to stitch this data together.